# "What is it here?" — Does it mean "What is this place?" or "What is in here?" or "What are you doing here?"

Tags: meaning

**"What is it here?"** [BBC-Tweenies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eA-ylcVkAM) (see:0:00-0:07)

This is what the subtitles say. If the subtitles are correct, this is the first time I have heard this structure.

However, just by looking at the question, it can mean–to me–all of the following:

It can mean **"What is this place? / What is the name of this place?"**
(Does the speaker just want to find out what the room is called?)

Or it can also mean **"What is there in this place? / What is in here?"**
(Does the speaker want to see the materials inside the room?)

And it can also mean  **What are you doing here?/What are up to in this place?"**

Am I right in my thinking?

---

If the subtitles aren't correct, what is he saying?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the subtitles are wrong. If you slow it down it is more cherent and sounds like "What's he doing ... Max, what're you doing".

Comment: No, the speaker is talking to Max. So, he can't be saying "What is he doing?"

Comment: I think he says "What's in here?" - referring to the broom cupboard.

Comment: Just listened again and I now hear "What's in here Max?" as Kate says. It's very slurred and I can still hear a D at the start of "here" which is what I think confused me.

Comment: @KateBunting , timchessish , He's saying "What's in there, Max?"

Comment: 'What's in 'ere, Max?' in a sort of London accent.

Comment: I've added a line o your post because I think i will make the question useful for other user. And also it might allow me to write an answer that could help you with your listening skills. :) However, if you are unhappy with the edit, please don't hesitate to roll it back. (I think, though, that the question might get closed in that case, because someone will say 'this question is based upon a misunderstanding' or something like that)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It's what's in there' in a London accent with antecipatory assimilation of the [n] and retropsective assimilation of the dental fricative [ð]. He's not saying '*here*' without an [h], he's clearly saying *nere* where the [n] has replace the 'th'-sound. Try listening again! [Also Londoners pronounce never pronounce *here* with an AIR /SQUARE vowel!!!]

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. - **Nonsense**. I plugged in my decent headphones, and upped the volume, and he _very clearly_ says **'What's in 'ere, Max'?**

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Nonsense yourself! I've done the same, and I've also asked a room full of phoneticians right here now, most of us from London, and they ***all*** say  he's saying 'what's in nere' as in 'what's in there'.

Comment: Heaven forbid I should _ever_ enter a room full of phoneticians from London!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey We're fun people!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without doing a phonetic analysis, but looking at the wider context, my interpretation is "What's in 'ere, Max" with "'ere" being a dropped-h pronunciation of "here".

Milo is talking to the dog, so the question is rhetorical.  He doesn't actually want the dog to answer, and from a scripting point of view, the purpose is to let the audience know that Milo is investigating the cupboard.

The range of pronunciations of [h]ere and [th]ere probably overlap slightly in muffled speech, but the former tends to sound more like "ear" whereas the latter is closer to "air".  I hear a vowel sound that is much closer to "ear".

Relative to the dog (Max), Milo is closer to the cupboard and can see inside it, so the cupboard is "here" and not "there".

However, it doesn't really matter.  Milo is rhetorically asking his dog "What is in the cupboard" as part of the storytelling structure of the show.  It probably wouldn't be natural for a speaker to do that. This is an artificial scripted speech, for the audience.

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer

The character is actually saying *there* not *here*.

[We can double-check this by comparing the vowel the speaker uses when he says the word *there* at 0.47, and then the word *here* at 1.02. He uses /eə/, as expected, for the word *there*. He uses /ɪə/, as expected, for the word *here*. In the Original Poster's clip, the speaker uses a very clear /eə/-vowel].

---

## Full answer

What the Original Poster is hearing is this:

> [**'wɒss ɪn̪ 'n̪eə mæks**]

Notice that I have used square brackets for the phonetics, [ ]. This is because we need a detailed description of the sound, not just a list of the phonemes. When we just give a list of the phonemes we use slanty brackets, /  /. The important detail in the transcription here is the little upside down 'tooth' symbol underneath the two 'n's. The little symbols that appear above or below the 'letters' in a transcription are called 'diacritics'. We will come back to the diacritics soon.

Now, a different speaker, speaking slowly and very pedantically, very fussily, might pronounce the same sentence like this:

> [**'wɒts ɪn̪ 'ðeə mæks**]

In other words the speaker is pronouncing the following sentence:

> What's in there, Max?

Notice that the second transcription has the voiced th' sound, [ð], at the beginning of the word *there*. And also that it still has an upside-down tooth diacritic under the 'n'.

### **Why does the sentence sound like that**

When we speak, our mouths are always preparing for the sound that are coming up a bit later. We also have to make small adjustments to move smoothly from one sound to the other. Sometimes English (like other languages) has rules which specifically allow one sound to change to another when next to other particular sounds.

When one sound becomes more like another, we call this *assimilation*. Most assimilation in English is *anticipatory* which means that a particular sound (the technical word is 'segment') becomes more like the sound that will come after it. This is what is happening in the first word *Whats*:

> 1. /wɒts/
> 2. /wɒss/

In (1) we see a typical careful pronunciation of the word *what's*. The last two sounds there are both made with the tongue at the same place in the mouth. Just behind your teeth there is a little shelf which slopes upwards. It's called the *alveolar ridge*. English speakers make a lot of their sounds on the alveolar ridge:

- /t, d, n, l, s, z/

These are the first sounds in the words *sip*, *dip*, *nip*, *lip*, *sip* and *zip*. These sounds are very unstable in English and often change their place of articulation (the place they are made in the mouth) and also often their manner (the  way the sound is made). In fast speech, the /t/ in the word *what* can keep its voiceless quality, keep its place of articulation on the alveolar ridge but change the type of sound so that it becomes sibilant. This means that it becomes the same as the following /s/ segment. We thus get /wɒss/.

Out of all the alveolar sounds, the one that is most likely to change it's place of articulation is the sound /n/. This sound will most often change to match the place of articulation of a following consonant.  Before a /p, b, m/ and (to a lesser extent) /w/ it will often become an /m/. Before a /k/ or a /g/ it will often have the 'ng' sound, /ŋ/. This is how the word *ten* might change:

- te**m** people
- te**m** bananas
- te**m** minutes
- the te**m** wonders of the world
- te**ng** carrots
- te**ng** grapes

An /n/ will also nearly always change when it occurs before a 'th' sound, for example the unvoiced sound at the beginning of the word *things*, or the voiced sound at the beginning of the word *there*. These are the sounds /ð/ and /θ/, the *dental fricatives*.  These sounds are made using the tongue on the back of the upper teeth. When an /n/ occurs before a 'th' sound it will also change its place of articulation and become dental, although it will still be nasal. [A native English speaker will not notice this, but will be able to feel that the place they are making the /n/ is now on the teeth if they check.]. When we make a detailed transcription we use an upside down 'tooth' diacritic under the /n/:

- [ten̪ θɪŋz] *ten things*
- [ɪn̪ ðeə] *in there*

However, when an /n/ occurs before a voiced dental fricative, the sound /ð/, it can often also cause the /ð/ to change. In other words we get *perseverative* assimilation, where a sound causes the following sound to change. This time the /n/ causes the /ð/ to also become nasal. This means that the two sounds have both become more like each other. They are now both dental nasals, [ n̪ ].

### Summary

So in the Youtube video, the  /t/ in *what's* becomes an /s/, and the /n/ in *in* and the /ð/ in *there* both become dental nasals  [n̪], to give  ['wɒ**s**s ɪ**n̪** '**n̪**eə mæks].

Very often, when we get a lot of small function words together, we often have large numbers of alveolar and dental consonants jostling together. These very often change in many different ways and may even disappear altogether or join up with other sounds to make completely new ones. This means that there may be a large number of different possible pronunciations of the same type of sentence. And all of this can  make it very difficult for speech recognition software to tell what the actual words are. They're not as good as humans yet!

Comment: This is about hearing it  and Michael Harvey is right. The character is saying **in 'ere** which is due to the fact of it referring to a closet. Now, what's in here? in a non-London accent. As for the room full of phoneticians, they seem to be hearing deficient...

Comment: @Lambie As a native British English phonetician specialising in Southern British English,  I beg to differ.  And the evidence is absolutely plain. First of all, nobody with his accent ever uses a SQUARE vowel for the word *here*; They use the NEAR vowel. Secondly, at 0.47 you can very clearly hear a clear pronunciation of the word *there* with no assimilation. He uses a very, very clear SQUARE vowel. At 1.02 exactly, he says a very, very clear version of the word *here*. And this time the vowel is nothing like a square vowel but a very, very clear NEAR vowel.

Comment: @Lambie You can clearly hear how the character pronounces the vowels in those two words. This is absolutely cut and dried evidence that the speaker uses SQUARE for *there* and NEAR for *here*. The word *here* is not even a vague possibility, therefore, for the excerpt in question! And all my colleagues here agree

Comment: Your explanation is way over the top for an ELL. What's more: in 'ere or inere is deictically feasible. Why would a character be saying "there" when he's practically inside the closet himself?

Comment: There's laudable effort here, but I would argue that it does the community no favors to answer an off-topic question. If the problem was in hearing what was said, transcription is off-topic. If the OP wished to edit to make this more clearly a question about pronunciation patterns, that's different.

Comment: @AndyBonner ???? *If the problem was in hearing what was said, transcription is off-topic* <--What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: Oh, just that a simple "what does this audio say" question is off-topic here. This answer has kind of moved into a discussion of pronunciation, which *is* on-topic, but it doesn't seem to have been the original request.

Comment: @Lambie - 'way over the top' - you are being restrained.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey ,  Lambie Are you saying that Yunus cannot understand the post? Why do you think so?

Comment: Certainly not. I NEVER criticize a person for asking a question like this, English language learning or not. What an idea.

Comment: @Lambie I wasn't implying criticism of Yunus on your part. Don't know *where* you got that from. I was stating that you thought the explanation was over the top for OP. // However, this kind of assimilation is regularly covered in teaching materials for advanced students. I was simply asking them if you were correct and it was badly aimed.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. No, your explanation is way too complicated for this question. Advanced students of linguistics, not English language learners.

Comment: @Lambie No. Covered in B2/C1-level course books and student activity books.

Comment: @Lambie For example, here: [Pronunciation Games](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pronunciation-Games-Cambridge-Copy-Collection/dp/0521467357)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.That really made me LOL. It's like a beginner's ABCs-looking thing. Of course they need to learn pronunciation. I can't see the contents of that book at all. But using diacriticals like this: 'wɒts ɪn̪ 'ðeə mæks is simply over the top. I find John Trim's little book, though RP (and which I adapted to non-RP and AmE), to be enough to give students the basic re pronunciation and spelling they need: youtube.com/watch?v=7guj-_7QIgk And I still think your explanation above is better suited for a 101 course in phonetics and phonemics than English learners. –